# Nicer syntax for setting default argument value to default constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, optional-parameters, default-constructor

One might want to declare a function with an argument, and specify that the default value for the argument is the result of the type's default constructor:

```
void foo(a::really::long::type::name arg = a::really::long::type::name());
```

Is there a nicer syntax for this that doesn't involve entering the type name twice? Something like:

```
void foo(a::really::long::type::name arg = default);
```

I realize I can `typedef` the type name to make it prettier, but I'm curious whether such a syntax exists.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes:

```
void foo(a::really::long::type::name arg = {});
```

To sum up the following standard definitions:

This is list initialization. Depending of the type, aggregate initialization is performed or the object is value initialized, which in turn implies default initialized or zero initialized.

Some "corner" cases are when the type is a specialization of `std::initializer_list` or when the type has a `std::initializer_list` constructor (it is called if it has no default constructor)

---

The relevant standard quotes (in order we encounter definitions):

§8.3.6 Default arguments [dcl.fct.default]

> 1 If an initializer-clause is specified in a parameter-declaration this
>   initializer-clause is used as a default argument
>
> 5 The default argument has the same semantic constraints as the
>   initializer in a declaration of a variable of the parameter type,
>   using the copy-initialization semantics (8.5)

§8.5.4 List-initialization [dcl.init.list]

> 1 List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list. Such an initializer is called an initializer
>   list, [...]. An initializer list may be empty. List-initialization can
>   occur in direct-initialization or copy initialization contexts;
>   [..] list-initialization in a
>   copy-initialization context is called copy-list-initialization.
>
> 3 List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - If T is an aggregate, **aggregate initialization is performed** (8.5.1)
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements and T is a class
>     type with a default constructor, the object is **value-initialized**.
> - Otherwise, if T is a specialization of std::initializer_list, a prvalue initializer_list object is constructed as described below and
>     used to initialize the object according to the rules for
>     initialization of an object from a class of the same type (8.5).
> - Otherwise, if T is a class type, constructors are considered. The applicable constructors are enumerated and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3, 13.3.1.7) [...]
> - ...
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is **value-initialized**.

§ 8.5 Initializers  [dcl.init]

> 8 To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is
>     user-provided or deleted, then the object is **default-initialized**;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is **zero-initialized**
>     and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked,
>     and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is
>     **default-initialized**;
> - if T is an array type, then each element is **value-initialized**;
> - otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**
>
> 7  To **default-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), **the default constructor (12.1) for T is called** (and the initialization is
>     ill-formed if T has no default constructor or overload resolution
>     (13.3) results in an ambiguity or in a function that is deleted or
>     inaccessible from the context of the initialization);
> - if T is an array type, each element is **default-initialized**;
> - otherwise, no initialization is performed.
>
> 6 To **zero-initialize** an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained by converting the integer literal 0 (zero) to T;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is
>     zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zero-initialized and padding is
>     initialized to zero bits;
> - if T is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if T is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

§13.3.1.7 Initialization by list-initialization [over.match.list]

> 1 When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized
>   (8.5.4), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> - Initially, the candidate functions are the **initializer-list constructors** (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of
>     the initializer list as a single argument.
> - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all
>     the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the
>     elements of the initializer list.
>
> If the initializer list has no elements and T has a default
>   constructor, the first phase is omitted. [...]

Comment: It isn't quite value-initialization.

Comment: @bolov Are you sure it cannot produce empty initializer list? And your link contains following text: "In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, __aggregate-initialization__ is performed instead of __value-initialization__."

Comment: It can also call a `initializer_list` constructor, if the class has one and doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: @bolov So you say that _usually_ this way does what you mean. : ) This way should be used carefully in common templates, I think.

Answer (score 3):

A pedestrian approach is possible, if you control the class of `arg`. Use a conversion constructor overloaded for an `enum`:

```
// Define this enum, and then write constructors which take dfl
enum dfl { dflval };

class a_really_long_type_name {
public:
  a_really_long_type_name(dfl arg = dflval);
};
```

Now foo can be:

```
void foo(a_really_long_type_name arg = dflval);
```

If you can apply this, a benefit is portability; this should work fine in a twenty-five-year-old C++ compiler.

Multiple classes can all share this `dfl` `enum` and its `dflval`-flavored zero; it's like having a new keyword.

Because an `enum` is a distinct type, this doesn't interfere with constructor overloads for integer types or characters and so on.

The downside is working it into some classes which already have default construction provided via argument defaulting, which leads to duplicate constructor code.